# Does anyone have a Windows "at /every:" example to explain how to setup a batch file to run every day?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, command-line-interface, batch-file

Microsoft documentation for the "AT" scheduler command shows that it has an /every: switch to schedule a script to reoccur on specified days. I've done it before, but I can't remember the syntax for that switch. The documentation does not include an example that uses the /every: switch.

So, can you help me write an example "AT" scheduler command to run a batch file on the local machine daily, monday through friday?

Example:

```
c:\at 12:01am /every: updatestats.bat
```

Comment: Side note: On recent versions of Windows `schtasks` can be used as it supports more features of the task scheduler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running every day:

```
AT 3:00AM /EVERY:M,T,W,Th,F,S,Su c:\foo.bat
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work in Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise for me. Any ideas? He's complaining about an illegal value for the option `every`. Not even `/EVERY:M` is working !?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
/every:monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday
```